# int doesn't work in def within regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex, string, string-formatting

I need to write function which takes a count and a string and return a list of all of the words in the string that are count word characters long or longer.

My function is:

```
import re

def find_words(count, a_str):
    count = int(count)
    return re.findall(r'\w{},'.format(int(count)), a_str)
```

But it doesn't work, it is return empty list:

Example:

```
find_words(4, "dog, cat, baby, balloon, me")
```

Should return:

```
['baby', 'balloon']
```

Answer (score 3):

The regex isn't correct. The `{}` is interpreted as placeholder for `format`, but you want it to be the regexs' `{}` which specifies the number of repeats. You need to use `r'\w{{{}}}'` here. Observe the difference:

```
>>> r'\w{},'.format(4)
'\\w4,'

>>> r'\w{{{},}}'.format(4)
'\\w{4,}'
```

And then it works correctly:

```
import re
def find_words(count, a_str):
    count = int(count)
    return re.findall(r'\w{{{},}}'.format(count), a_str)

>>> find_words(4, "dog, cat, baby, balloon, me") 
['baby', 'balloon']
```

Comment: Thanks, but why it is needed {{{}}} instead of just {{}}?

Comment: @Dmitriy_kzn The docs say "If you need to include a brace character in the literal text, it can be escaped by doubling: `{{` and `}}`." ["Format String Syntax"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) And you want to keep one brace character in the literal text for the regex but you also want to insert the `count`. So `{{` so it keeps the `{` and one `{` for the formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Why RegExp?

```
>>> string = "dog, cat, baby, balloon, me"
>>> [word for word in string.split(', ') if len(word) >= 4]
['baby', 'balloon']
```

So function could be something like follow:

```
>>> def find_words(count, a_str):
...     return [word for word in a_str.split(', ') if len(word) >= count]
...
>>> find_words(4, 'dog, cat, baby, balloon, me')
['baby', 'balloon']
```

Comment: This is better than the regex version if you input a silly but valid count, like 0 or -1

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
def find_words(count, a_str):
   s = [re.findall("\w{"+str(count)+",}", i) for i in ["dog, cat, baby, balloon, me"]]
   return s[0]

print(find_words(4, ["dog, cat, baby, balloon, me"]))
```

Output:

```
['baby', 'balloon']
```